# When using --negotiate with curl, is a keytab file required?

Tags: hadoop, curl, kerberos, webhdfs, keytab

The [documentation](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html) describing how to connect to a kerberos secured endpoint shows the following:

```
curl -i --negotiate -u : "http://<HOST>:<PORT>/webhdfs/v1/<PATH>?op=..."
```

The `-u` flag has to be provided but is ignored by curl.

Does the `--negotiate` option cause curl to look for a keytab that was created beforehand with the `kinit` command, or will curl prompt for credentials?

If it looks for a keytab file, what filename will the command be looking for?

Comment: curl tries to get a valid ticket **in the cache** (cf. env variable `KRB5CCNAME` or by default `FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_$(id -u)` on Unix / `API:` on Windows) -- it does not care how the ticket was created.

Comment: Caveat: the Windows versions of curl are compiled to support the Microsoft SSPI libraries, not the GSSAPI libraries that are required by Hadoop REST services.

Comment: BTW a keytab is a file containing a hashed password, created by `ktutil` on Linux or by an Active Directory utility like `ktpass.exe`. It is **used** by `kinit`, not **created**.

Comment: Even better: if you update your question so that it is more specific, I can make a more specific answer *(e.g. do you want to SPNEGO each time, or just once to get the reusable Delegation Token? do you want to know why HttpFs uses a signed cookie instead of  the actual Token like WebHDFS does? are you worried about the lack of consistency checks using WebHDFS vs. using the Java API? etc.)*

Comment: An extra hint at no additional cost: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37459073/accessing-kerberos-secured-webhdfs-without-spnego/37480236#37480236

Comment: Thanks Samsom.  I've just started exploring this area, so I don't have the knowledge to make my question more specific yet.  I will post more as my knowledge builds.

Comment: @SHC Were you able to properly resolve the issue? Otherwise I would add a qualified answer.

Comment: Thanks, do you know how can we do the same in a Java http client, ie. Authorize the proxy using a keytab file?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Being a once-in-a-while-contributor to `curl` in that area. Here is what you need to know:

`curl(1)` itself knows nothing about Kerberos and will not interact neither with your credential cache nor your keytab file. It will delegate all calls to a GSS-API implementation which will do the magic for you. What magic depends on the library, Heimdal and MIT Kerberos.

Based on your question, I assume that you have little knowledge about Kerberos and want simply automate API calls to a REST endpoints secured by SPNEGO.

Here is what you need to do:

1. Have a Unix-like OS
2. Install at least MIT Kerberos 1.11
3. Install at least `curl` 7.38.0 against MIT Kerberos
4. Verify this with `curl --version` mentioning GSS-API **and** SPNEGO and with `ldd` linked against your MIT Kerberos version.
5. Create a **client** keytab for the service principal with `ktutil` or `mskutil`
6. Try to obtain a TGT with that **client** keytab by `kinit -k -t <path-to-keytab> <principal-from-keytab>`
7. Verify with `klist` that you have a ticket cache

Environment is now ready to go:

8. Export `KRB5CCNAME=<some-non-default-path>`
9. Export `KRB5_CLIENT_KTNAME=<path-to-keytab>`
10. Invoke `curl --negotiate -u : <URL>`

MIT Kerberos will detect that both environment variables are set, inspect them, automatically obtain a TGT with your keytab, request a service ticket and pass to `curl`. You are done.

**Note**: this will not work with Heimdal.

Comment: Can you detail how exactly in step-3 do we install curl *against* MIT Kerberos?

Comment: @displayName at best, your OS package manager will do this for you. At worst, you need to pass the pass the path of `krb5-config` to the configure script of curl. That's it.

Comment: What is `KRB5CCNAME` supposed to be set to?

Comment: @wheeler See https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.12/doc/basic/ccache_def.html

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question. Does it need to point to an existing file or something? What, _specifically_ do I set the `KRB5CCNAME` environment variable to?

Comment: @wheeler A late answer, but you set it with path to kerberos cache file, e.g. `export KRB5CCNAME=/tmp/krb5cc_1000`. After using kinit, the cache is created automatically, you can find it using `klist`: __Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000__

Comment: +9000 for this post.  This is a Top 5 G.O.A.T. for me.  Before I read this post, I never knew that Linux/Cygwin /usr/bin/curl with GSS-API + SPNEGO was using MIT Kerberos lib for auth.  Blew my mind.  There is no hint from the curl error.  Only: `gss_init_sec_context() failed: SPNEGO cannot find mechanisms to negotiate.`  Another good tip: Enable MIT Kerberos debug logs: `env KRB5_TRACE=/dev/stdout curl ...`

Answer (score 18):

1. Check curl version

   `$ curl -V` - It should support the feature "GSS-Negotiate"
2. Login using `kinit`

   `$ kinit <user-id>`
3. Use curl

   `$ curl --negotiate -u : -b ~/cookiejar.txt -c ~/cookiejar.txt http://localhost:14000/webhdfs/v1/?op=liststatus`

   "--negotiate" option enables SPNEGO

   "-u" option is required but ignored (the principle specified during kinit is used)

   "-b" & "-c" options are used to store and send http cookies.

Comment: It should not support `GSS-Negotiate` because all these version are broken prior 7.38.0. It has to support `SPNEGO`.

Comment: This works fine for me, and is a lot less setup/trouble than the accepted answer. curl 7.35.0, no SPNEGO, only GSS-Negotiate.

Comment: Are the cookie options necessary for a basic test of connectivity? If yes, why?

Comment: Answering myself: without cookiejar the http will redirect infinitely even though the Kerberos part was successful.

Comment: @Michael-O I, too, am using a pre-7.38 version with SPNEGO with no issue. `curl 7.29.0 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.29.0 NSS/3.28.4 zlib/1.2.7 libidn/1.28 libssh2/1.4.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz unix-sockets`. `GSS-Negotiate` appears to be the ticket.

Comment: I'm having the same problem but none of the answers seem to help. Would you mind having a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59898525/curl-with-negotiate-kerberos-doesnt-seem-to-work maybe you can spot a mistake :-)

Answer (score 0):

I am using version 7.54.0. The following command works fine for me. (please remember/pay attention there are double dashes before the negotiate option).

```
curl --negotiate -u: '<the_full_url>'
```