# curl with kerberos authentication

Tags: shell, macos-sierra

I have a Kerberos(Heimdal) authenticated site and I need to curl the website content into my Mac terminal.

Gone through many sites, and found a solution for this in stack overflow, but that doesn't work for Heimdal. ([When using --negotiate with curl, is a keytab file required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38509837/when-using-negotiate-with-curl-is-a-keytab-file-required)) So expecting a clear explanation on this. Thanks in advance.