# SPNEGO authentication with uri module

Tags: http, ansible, uri, kerberos, spnego

Using curl I can access HTTP resource on a Web service with Kerberos / SPNEGO this way, after I did a `kinit`

```
curl -x POST --negotiate -u : http://host.mydomain.net:14000/my/web/resource
```

You can see I just pass `-u :` without actually passing any user / password and it works because of `--negotiate`

With ansible I can access the resource but I need to put my credentials

```
 - uri:
     url: "http://host.mydomain.net:14000/my/web/resource"
     return_content: true
     method: POST
     headers:
       Content-Type: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
     user: "{{ myuser }}"
     password: "{{ mypass }}"
   register: login

 - debug:
     msg: "{{ login.content }}"
```

Now I like to access the resource only using Kerberos authentication so the executor will use it's credentials, I tried to define `user` and `password` parameters empty but this fails.

So I'd like to know if `uri` module support SPNEGO and how I should do?

Thanks

Comment: did you figure out an alternate solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curl comitter here...

This will not work. Curl cannot authenticate for you. The authentication has to happen at logon time to the machine/server. Since you want to automate that, create a service account, export the keytab and provide the keytab file with the env var `KRB5_CLIENT_KTNAME` to Ansible. This will work, but you need MIT Kerberos.

Please read my [canonical answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38664954/696632) to this. If you are in a Active Directory environment, you can easily use `msktutil(1)` which will do all the magic for you.