# Intermittent problems with querying data from druid using SQL

Tags: druid

I query data from druid via SQL. Sometimes it succeeds, but sometimes it fails. My query uses curl; it is:

```
curl --negotiate -u:srvadmin  -X POST -H'Content-Type: application/json' http://du-s12-idc:8082/druid/v2/sql -d @query.json.
```

When it fails, I get this response:

```
{"error":"Unknown exception","errorMessage":"Failure getting results for query[6639c357-441f-456c-9a01-0f7ffd0758b7] url[http://du-s28-idc:8083/druid/v2/] because of [Invalid type marker byte 0x3c for expected value token\n at [Source: (SequenceInputStream); line: -1, column:
```

1]]","errorClass":"io.druid.java.util.common.RE","host":null}

The file query.json is simple:

```
{"query":"select * from bds_dsp_media_run_info_h_1016 limit 3"}
```

The data was loaded from hadoop to druid and succeeded. My druid version was 0.11 and built in a cluster with Kerberos.

Does anyone have this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think `Invalid type marker byte 0x3c...` exception is just uninformative response that tells you that the server has an internal error, but doesn't give you a clue on what is actually happening. It would help a lot if you could check broker logs when the request is happening.

But, to play a guessing game - I would expect it to be a Kerberos issue. Do you have `KRB5_CLIENT_KTNAME` env variable populated with the path to your key file?

Comment: the broker log  when i get response is :Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Invalid type marker byte 0x3c for expected value token

Comment: actually ,i'm new to kerberos.i use ambari to install the kerberos. KRB5_CLIENT_KTNAME env variable may influence the  curl request？

Comment: That variable should point to a keytab file that is used to authenticate with Kerberos. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/38664954/1130863 for more info. Honestly, I don't know whether it's a cause of the issue, but might be worth it to try