# How to create a kerberized application?

Tags: kerberos

I'm currently learning about Kerberos and all the details of it. Learned how to set up a Kerberos KDC and admin server on Ubuntu, and I can now create user principals and get a TGT using `kinit` etc.

What I didn't get is how does an application authenticate users. I get the theory, but I want to see it in action. So what I want to do is write a small HTTP application in Linux (C/C++) and have it authenticate users based on Kerberos tickets.

I've been searching the web but couldn't find anything. Could someone give me a hint where to start?

Answer (score 0):

Turn on Tracing for kerberos on Linux this is easy: (do this first it will start giving you feedback)

```
env KRB5_TRACE=/dev/stdout
```

Then you could use Curl as @Michael-O said, but with verbose logging turned on that would help you get a feel for things.  ([as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38509837/when-using-negotiate-with-curl-is-a-keytab-file-required))
Check curl version

> $ curl -V  #- It should support the feature "GSS-Negotiate"
>
> Login using kinit
>
> $ kinit
>
> Use curl
>
> $ curl -v --negotiate -u : -b ~/cookiejar.txt -c ~/cookiejar.txt
> http://localhost:14000/webhdfs/v1/?op=liststatus
>
> "--negotiate" option enables SPNEGO
>
> "-u" option is required but ignored (the principle specified during
> kinit is used)
>
> "-b" & "-c" options are used to store and send http cookies.

SPNEGO is a authentication mechanism that knows how to facilitate kerberos via GSS-Negotiate.  THis would be the fastest way to get a feel for things but it's a lot of logs and not always the most clear.

Comment: 1, SPNEGO is NOT an authorization mechanism, 2. Kerberod does NOT negotiate.

Comment: @Michael-O - Spengo facilitates the authorization engine.  Probably loosely could could be called an authorization mechanism/component. If you want to add more to the conversation maybe you could explain your opinions.

Comment: Still wrong, read the difference between authentication and authorization.

Comment: I have corrected it. I know the difference but clearly used the wrong one.

Answer (score 0):

> What I didn't get is how does an application authenticate users. I get the theory, but I want to see it in action. So what I want to do is write a small HTTP application in Linux (C/C++) and have it authenticate users based on Kerberos tickets.

For the server, I would choose one of these options:

- Apache with the `mod_auth_gssapi` module (*not* the old mod_auth_kerb... but it works too),
- or Python using Flask and flask-gssapi (good choice if you want to see how the underlying `gssapi` [functions](https://github.com/COUR4G3/flask-gssapi/blob/master/flask_gssapi.py#L55-L57) are used).

There are several others, e.g. Golang's [gokrb5](https://github.com/jcmturner/gokrb5/blob/master/v8/USAGE.md#spnegokerberos-http-service) has an SPNEGO example.

In all cases, the *GSS-API* (or the Windows equivalent, SSPI) will be used on both the client and server, starting with gss_init_sec_context(). The "direct" Kerberos functions are generally not used in programs (except old ones that predate GSS-API).

(Note that normally GSS-API produces raw Kerberos tokens, but with HTTP Negotiate auth they're wrapped inside SPNEGO tokens, so you have to specifically request the SPNEGO mechanism when initializing GSS-API.)

Answer (score -2):

Use curl, it has everything builtin.