# Authenticate to Hadoop REST API via keytab file from WIndows domain

Tags: rest, hadoop, kerberos, webrequest

I'm trying to access Kerberized Hadoop cluster REST APIs from my .NET client using WebRequests. I'm using credentials from my ActiveDirectory domain, which has trust relations with the Hadoop realm:

```
 NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password", "ACTIVEDIRECTORY.DOMAIN");
 WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(System.Uri.EscapeUriString(url));
 request.Credentials = credentials;
 request.Method = "GET";
 WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
```

My workflow works fine as I see 3 responses on my requests:

```
 HTTP/1.1 401 Authentication required
 HTTP/1.1 307 TEMPORARY_REDIRECT
 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

In my second request I see a Kerberos token sent as a separate security header:

```
 Authorization: Negotiate YIIDXAYGKwYBBQUCoIIDUDCCA...
```

But this is my UPN account and I want to replace it with the SPN with a keytab instead of password as application will act as a standalone WCF service and I don't want to mess with web config security containers.

So my questions are:

1) Is it possible to use keytab instead my UPN creadentials to generate SPENGO Negotiate token after the first request?

2) Is there any way to use already obtained ticket from by cache in my WebRequest object?

3) How my Kerberos token is been generated? Is it an GSSAPI-encripted by  version of my Username-Password?

I was trying to use MIT Kerberos Manager utilites for that by not much progress there.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you ever find a "native" .NET way to connect to Kerberized Hadoop, please blog about it...! So far, I use a dirty workaround with a tiny Java utility to manage the initial SPNEGO *(requires a keytab c/o `ktpass.exe` if you use AD as a Kerberos back-end)* and retrieve the Hadoop delegation token that you can use for the rest of the session; cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37459073/accessing-kerberos-secured-webhdfs-without-spnego/37480236#37480236

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter Thanks for the tip. And yes,I will blog this if I will find a way how to do it